# Compare valid user input with a list and return error message

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program where the user types in two football teams. The teams can't be equal. The problem I have is that my program writes my error message multiple times(everytime it doesn't find it in the list). Is there anyway to get around this without completely rewrite the code??

```
teamlist = ["arsenal", "liverpool", "manchester", "newcastle"]

def finding_team(home_or_away):
    while True:
        user_input = input("Type in " + home_or_away + " team: " )
        for team in teamlist:
            if team.upper() == user_input.upper():
                return team
            else:
                print("Didn't get that, try again")
                continue
def team_input():
    print()
    hometeam = finding_team("HOME")
    awayteam = finding_team("AWAY")
    while hometeam == awayteam:
        print("The away team can't be the same as the home team!")
        awayteam = finding_team("AWAY")
    return(hometeam, awayteam)


the_teams = team_input()
print("The teams you typed in are ", the_teams)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
teamlist = ["arsenal", "liverpool", "manchester", "newcastle"]

def finding_team(home_or_away):
    while True:
        team = input("Type in " + home_or_away + " team: " )
        if team.lower() in teamlist:
            return team
        else:
            print("Didn't get that, try again")

def team_input():
    print()
    hometeam = finding_team("HOME")
    awayteam = finding_team("AWAY")
    while hometeam == awayteam:
        print("The away team can't be the same as the home team!")
        awayteam = finding_team("AWAY")
    return(hometeam, awayteam)

the_teams = team_input()
print("The teams you typed in are ", the_teams)
```

I changed it so that the user's input (stored in `team`) is checked against all items in `teamlist` in a single conditional statement.

```
Type in HOME team: foo
Didn't get that, try again
Type in HOME team: arsenal
Type in AWAY team: arsenal
The away team can't be the same as the home team!
Type in AWAY team: manchester
The teams you typed in are  ('arsenal', 'manchester')
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I also want the program to except input with upper/lowercase letters. I tries to solve this with "if team.upper() == user_input.upper()" but now I can't use that anymore.

Comment: @PeterNydahl This code should work just fine if the user enters e.g. "Arsenal" instead of "arsenal" if that's what you're asking. All values you entered in `teamlist` are lower-case, and the user's input will be coerced to lowercase through `.lower()`

Comment: Yes it works, but let's say that the teams names in the list begins with upper-case(Arsenal, Manchester etc), how do I fix that? Sorry I forgot to be clear about this in the question!

Comment: You could either just ensure all items in `teamlist` are lower-case or you can replace `if team.lower() in teamlist:` with `if team.lower() in [x.lower() for x in teamlist]:`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check if your teams are in teamliste, you don't need that for loop.

```
teamlist = ["arsenal", "liverpool", "manchester", "newcastle"]

def finding_team(home_or_away):
    while True:
        user_input = input("Type in " + home_or_away + " team: " )
        if user_input.lower() in teamlist:
            return user_input.upper()
        else:
            print("Didn't get that, try again")

def team_input():
    print()
    hometeam = finding_team("HOME")
    awayteam = finding_team("AWAY")
    while hometeam == awayteam:
        print("The away team can't be the same as the home team!")
        awayteam = finding_team("AWAY")
    return(hometeam, awayteam)


the_teams = team_input()
print("The teams you typed in are ", the_teams)
```